# Turning XML from HTTP request into hash

Tags: ruby, xml

I'm making a HTTP request to a public IMDb-style TV episode service. I'm returned data like

```
<title>The X-Files</title>
<episodes>202</episodes>
<ended>Yes</ended>
```

And I want to work with that data in my program. Ultimately, I want to use it to form an `SQL` statement and insert the data into my database.

However, actually turning the data into a hash is harder than I expected. I googled it, and there are a lot of gems that purport to help, like `Simple-XML` -- but they expect files, and don't seem to behave when I pass them an object containing XML instead.

What's the common and accepted way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse normal data as well using SimpleXML gem. Assuming you have installed `xml-simple` gem already, do

```
require 'xmlsimple'
xml_str = "<data><title>The X-Files</title><episodes>202</episodes><ended>Yes</ended></data>"
xml_dict = XmlSimple.xml_in(xml_str)
```

The `xml_str` variable can be constructed from the http response.

Note that the current data you have `<title>The X-Files</title><episodes>202</episodes><ended>Yes</ended>` is not valid xml (it looks valid markup but is not, you can check [here](http://www.xmlvalidation.com/)) and so I had to wrap them up within another parent `<data>` tag of its own.

Answer (score 1):

I use [HTTParty](http://rubygems.org/gems/httparty) when writing interfaces with services like that. It converts XML responses to a hash automatically. Provide your code and more details if you want a more detailed answer.